# How to create Folder in App specific folder Android

Tags: android

I want to create Folder in below path

`Internal storage/Android/media/{package name}/myfolder`

Can anyone ome help me to create "myfolder" ?

Comment: Well what is the problem using File.mkdir() ? But.. that is no valid path. Use a decent file explorer to know the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `adb shell` to access the shell.
Then you can navigate to the required directory using `cd` command, then `mkdir` to create the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using This Function you can Get your required Result.

private File createDirectory(String dirName) {
File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(dirName) + "/" + dirName);
if (!file.exists()) {
file.mkdir();
}
return file;
}